# Do flags timeout?

Tags: support, flags

I flagged a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507423/how-to-tether-an-andriod-phone-via-bluetooth) for mod attention as it look a better fit Android Enthusiasts. The question was since put on hold but my flag remains active.  I would have expected it to have either been disputed or declined as one of the users was voted to put on hold was 10K+ but perhaps it works differently as my flag was for mod attention?

So I assume this flag might be sitting there a while and this has got me wondering.  Do flags have a built in timeout, especially normal migrate flags or do they just sit in the queue forever until actioned one way or another?

Comment: Pretty sure there's no timeout, in theory it can sit in the queue for years as far as I can tell. :/

Comment: Oooh, that would *so* bother me...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You had flagged that question with a custom "Other" flag, so the flag couldn't be automatically cleared when the question was closed (since your flag could have been literally *anything*, there's no way to automatically tell if it was valid or not).

There is currently a bit of a flag backlog on "Other" flags on Stack Overflow, but we are working on it.  These flags won't just time out. We'll have to look at each one.